# How can I prove that this equality is not valid for any natural number?

Tags: divisibility, exponentiation, cubics

This is an old competition problem I am struggling with.

How can I prove that the equality $2^m = 4096c^3 + 192c^2+3c+1$ is not valid for any natural numbers $c$ and $m$ (and for $m=0$).

This equation has a solution only if $c=0$ (this is what I am trying to prove).

Comment: Please try not to use links to other places when they are not useful

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. The picture is in the form of a link, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: in this website something called mathjax is used to format the question, I will do it for this question :)

Comment: Nice to know, thank you.

Comment: Since $4096=2^{12}$, I recommend splitting into two cases: * $c$ is itself a power of $2$; * $2^k<c<2^{k+1}$ for some $k$. In either case, one should be able to identify the closest power(s) of $2$ to the right-hand side and show that it's not close enough to those powers to equal them.

Comment: If $c$ is  even, then the right side of your equation is odd, so the equation can't hold (except for the case $m=c=0$ that you already know). So you only need to consider odd values of $c$. (In other words, you can forget about the first case in @GregMartin's comment.) Also, it may be useful to notice that $64$ times the right side of your equation is $(64c+1)^3+63$.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, but it never ends. When I substitute c I get another variable which is not odd, and that process repeats.

Comment: Does anybody have another idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discriminant of the cubic equation is
$$\Delta=-110592 \,\left(2^{m+6}-63\right)^2 \quad < 0\quad \forall m$$ For the depressed equation $t^3+pt+q=0$, we have
$$\color{red}{\large p=0}  \qquad\text{and}\qquad \color{red}{\large 
q=\frac{63-2^{m+6}}{2^{18}}}$$

So, in the real domain, the only solution is
$$c=\frac{\Big[2^{m+6}-63\Big]^{\frac 13}-1}{64} $$